# Read n lines, and count the lines that do not contain the string "CD"

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, io

I would like to know how to improve the execution speed of the code below.

The context : **n** is an integer read from the stdin, and represents the number of cases. Each case is represented by a sequence of characters (can only be uppercase alphabet letters), that are read from stdin. For each case, if the sequence doesn't contain the sub-string *"CD"*, we add ***1***  to the variable `wins`.

Finally, we print out `wins` : the number of strings not containing the string "CD".

```
n = int(raw_input()) #number of cases
wins = 0
for i in range(n):
    if "CD" not in raw_input(): #count number of strings that doesn't contain "CD"
        wins += 1
print wins
```

Note: Official Python performance tips suggest using `map` or list comprehension instead of `for` loop  to speed up, but I couldn't implement those without the `for` loop.

What other ways to speed the execution speed, knowing that every thing read from the stdin is necessary, and that the typing speed (I use `python filename.py <input.txt` method) isn't an issue (I'm looking for a way pertaining to the code structure, to speed the execution itself) ?

Comment: Why delete [your old - hour ago - question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/176819)? You can always add more information by [edit]ing your question. Would you care to add the information about you doing something like `python file.py < something or other` that you deleted from the comments on the last question?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Thank you. I edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used better variable names, you wouldn't need your first comment. The second one, though, is pure noise as it just repeat the code without adding anything.

To save on memory (and thus a bit on speed as you won't need to allocate the array) you should use `xrange` rather than `range`.

You don't use the variable `i` so better call it `_` as it is a convention in Python for unused variables.

Lastly, you can use the `sum` built-in and a generator expression to perform the looping in C rather than in Python:

```
cases_count = int(raw_input())
wins = sum('CD' not in raw_input() for _ in xrange(cases_count))
print wins
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `xrange` instead of `range`.

If typing speed and such are not an issue, then `stdin` is a file. Treat it as a file- try reading the entire contents, or using `for line in sys.stdin,` or using `.readlines()`.